# Grouping a counted variable

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am quite new to SSRS and have what I imagine is a pretty simple question. I have the set up pictured below.

[image: Report set up]

What I'm looking for is a list of dates that data exists for then a nested list of outcomes and then how many of each of those outcomes there were on that date. What I get is this,

[image: Result]

I want 6/10/2016 > ABORT > to be 3 instead of 1 1 1. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that I need to change my query somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
=COUNT(Fields!sys_OUTCOME.Value,"sys_OUTCOME")
```

If you don't want to see details rows delete the `Details` group in the `Row Groups` pane.

**Code Explanation:**

> **COUNT**: Returns a count of non-null values specified by the expression,
>   evaluated in the context of the given scope.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx)

Every aggregation function can summarize data in a given context of the given scope. In this case the scope I passed to the `COUNT` function is "sys_OUTCOME" group name (Row Groups) so it will return the count of sys_OUTCOME values by sys_OUTCOME group. If you don't specify the group scope it will count every row without grouping what you was getting initially.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That seems to bring up #Error where the numbers used to be. Though there is only one line per outcome now which is closer to what I'm after.

Comment: It seems I forgot the `.Value` property. Try with the updated code.

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks. Would you mind adding a very brief explanation of that code and why it works? I'd like to understand what it means for the future.